# Add html attribute to model class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to add html attribute autocomplete to my input fields which are generated from my model class properties with `@Html.EditorForModel()`. Is there a way to add an attribute directly to the model property as an DataAnnotation of some sort or which approach would be best suitable?

I'm working in ASP.Net MVC 4. I have tried using annotations like `[HtmlAttribute("autocomplete", "name")]` but that does not work.

```
public class Person: EntityViewModel
{
    // [Add html attribute autocomplete = "email" here] 
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }

    // [Add html attribute autocomplete = "name" here] 
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In razor view, add attribute like @blah = model.value

Comment: The problem as I see it is that the input fields in the razer view is generated with @Html.EditorForModel() and therefor I cannot modify it. Maybe I misunderstand your suggestion?

Comment: It's not possible(and should not be possible) to set html attributes in the model. It must be done in html. `@Html.EditorForModel() ` can accept the template name as a parameter so I would suggest to create a razor template for you model and specify all required html attributes there(e.g. `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName, new { autocomplete = "name"  })`). If you will follow MVC name conventions(place a template in EditorTemplates folder and name it `Person.cshtml`) it even would not be necessary to specify template's name.

Comment: Thank you @RomanKoliada, then I know which direction to take.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Html.EditorForModel()
I suggest you use jquery **(if you have to use Html.EditorForModel())**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(":input").addClass("form-control");
});
```